# Dropdown menu and link to pages in pelican bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pelican

I'm working with the `pelican-bootstrap3` theme and I have a trivial question that I cannot solve by myself.

I have some pages and what I'd like to to is to create a dropdown menu for some pages of another page.

Suppose I have this situation:

```
├── content
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── about.md
│   │   ├── courses_list.md
│   │   └── first-corse.md
│   │   └── second-corse.md
```

and I'd like to have the main navbar with the `course-list` visible and `fist-course` and `second-course` as submenu of the dropdown.

The `html` piece of code I'm trying (without success) to edit is the `base.html`:

```
        {% if DISPLAY_PAGES_ON_MENU %}
            {% for p in pages | sort(attribute=PAGES_SORT_ATTRIBUTE) %}
                {% if p.url %}
                 <li{% if p == page %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ p.url }}">
                     {{ p.menulabel|default(p.title) }}
                  </a></li>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

Somebody has had a similar issue?

Thanks to all!

Comment: If the provided answer worked for you, don't forget to click the check mark to accept it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Pelican authors [does not prefer](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/1037) hierarchical menus (as an antipattern) in its core functionality. Instead, they welcome plugins or theme templates to handle this functionality if necessary.
So it is (merely) on your own to deploy that functionality.

There are (maybe more) themes on github adressing hierarchical menus, like [pelican-chameleon](https://github.com/yuex/pelican-chameleon) theme, using `MENUITEMS` definition like in this example taken from chameleon readme.

```
# works with chameleon theme
MENUITEMS = [
    ('Home', '/'),
    ('Archives', [
        ('Tags', '/tags.html'),
        ('Categories', '/categories.html'),
        ('Chronological', '/archives.html'),
        ]),
    ('Social', [
        ('Email', 'mailto: xx@yy'),
        ('Github', 'http://url-to-github-page'),
        ('Facebook', 'http://url-to-facebook-page'),
        ]),
    ]
```